# How to download artifact from command line without specifying repository URL?

Tags: maven, command-line-interface

Is it possible to download artifact from remote repository and cache it in local repository with maven from command line, while specifying artifact coordinates in command line, while remote repositories in `pom.xml`?

I tried command like this

```
mvn -f my\path\pom.xml org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get -Dartifact=mygroup:myartifact:myversion
```

but got

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get (default-cli)
>   on project myproject: The parameters 'repositoryUrl' for goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get are missing
>   or invalid

How to overcome?

Comment: have you tried out with pom.xml properties, or setting.xml profile properties ?

Comment: Maybe I Misunderstand what you like to do but `mvn clean package` exactly does this?

Comment: 1. whats about your settings.xml and 2. show us your pom.xml